# Can you create an input that changes?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am creating a quiz-like program and decided to define the 'while True' loop function (shown below) as a function. To do that, I need the input to change. However, I can't seem to do that no matter how many times I re-format the question. Here is the code:

```
def whiletrueloop():
    while True:
        choicenumber=input(choice)
        if choicenumber.lower() not in (options):
            print(repeatsentence)
        else:
            break

choice=("What is bigger, an elephant or a mouse?")
choicenumber=("choice1")
options=('elephant','mouse')
repeatsentence=("That isn't an answer!")
whiletrueloop()


if choicenumber=="elephant":
    print("Correct!")
elif choicenumber=="mouse":
    print("Wrong!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem with the code has to do with the scope of your choicenumber variable. You set it as a global variable with the line

```
choicenumber = ("choice1")
```

In the function, it is assigned locally to the input value, but it is the global scope variable that is used in the if-else decision at the end of the code. You can test this by inserting this option at the end of your code:

```
elif choicenumber == "choice1":
    print("Global!")
```

You'll always get "Global!" displayed, because the local value from the function is ignored in place of the global value.

There are a few ways around this. One is to declare the choicenumber variable as global inside the function:

```
while True:
    global choicenumber
    choicenumber=input(choice)
```

However, using global variables is considered bad practice, for reasons that you can look up.

An alternative is to use the function to return the value of choicenumber in response to the function call:

```
def whiletrueloop():
    while True:
        choicenumber=input(choice)
        if choicenumber.lower() not in (options):
            print(repeatsentence)
        else:
            return choicenumber

choice=("What is bigger, an elephant or a mouse?")
options=('elephant','mouse')
repeatsentence=("That isn't an answer!")

choicenumber = whiletrueloop()

if choicenumber=="elephant":
    print("Correct!")
elif choicenumber=="mouse":
    print("Wrong!")
```